# Magento 2 Clear Deleted Themes from List on the backend

Tags: magento2, theme

On my **Magento 2 Backend** > **Content** > **Configuration** and theme edit

There is a dropdown with the available themes.

The problem is that it's not just showing the available theme's, it's also show themes that I've already deleted.

See the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I clear the list from the already deleted ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you try to delete the theme manually and don't remove it from database. Find the `theme` table, need to remove your deleted theme.

If we want to uninstall theme, we should follow [the official Magento guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-theme-uninstall.html).